# How update other checkbox from checkbox

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

I've got a weird behaviour with my checkboxes :

I want to have 9 checkboxes : one for "week", one for "weekend" and 7 for all week days. When I click on "week" I want to set selected monday until friday and when I click on "weekend" saturday and sunday. I succeed in doing that but when I want to do the reverse (when I click on monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday and friday, I want to set selected week or same thing for weekend) it doesn't work.

I've noticed that in my valueChange functions, I need to do

`$scope.weekCBox = !$scope.weekCBox;` for updating my html checkbox week

but no for monday I find that really weird because they are defined in the same way :

Here is my html :

```
    <div style="display:block;">
         <b>Semaine</b>  
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="weekCbox.value"
                ng-change="valueWeekChange($index)"
                onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
    </div>
    <div style="display:block;">
         <b>Weekend</b> 
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="weekendCbox.value"
                 ng-change="valueWeekendChange($index)"
                 onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
   </div>
   <div style="display:block;">
         Lundi    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mondayCBox.value" 
                         ng-change="valueMondayChange($index)"
                         onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
         Mardi    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tuesdayCBox.value" ng-change="valueTuesdayChange($index)" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
         Mercredi <input type="checkbox" ng-model="wednesdayCBox.value" ng-change="valueWednesdayChange($index)" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
         Jeudi    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="thursdayCBox.value" ng-change="valueThursdayChange($index)" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
         Vendredi <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fridayCBox.value" ng-change="valueFridayChange($index)" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
         Samedi   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="saturdayCBox.value" ng-change="valueSaturdayChange($index)" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
         Dimanche <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sundayCBox.value" ng-change="valueSundayChange($index)" onkeypress='return (event.charCode >=45 && event.charCode <=57)||event.charCode==0'>
    </div>
```

and here is my JS code :

```
    $scope.mondayCBox = {
         value: false
    };
...
    $scope.weekendCBox = {
         value: false
    };

    $scope.valueWeekChange = function(index)
    {
        $scope.weekCBox.value = !$scope.weekCBox.value;
        $scope.mondayCBox.value = $scope.weekCBox.value;
        $scope.tuesdayCBox.value = $scope.weekCBox.value;
        $scope.wednesdayCBox.value = $scope.weekCBox.value;
        $scope.thursdayCBox.value = $scope.weekCBox.value;
        $scope.fridayCBox.value = $scope.weekCBox.value;
    }
    $scope.valueWeekendChange = function(index)
    {
        $scope.weekendCBox.value = !$scope.weekendCBox.value;
        $scope.saturdayCBox.value = $scope.weekendCBox.value;
        $scope.sundayCBox.value = $scope.weekendCBox.value;
    }
    $scope.valueMondayChange = function(index)
    {
        $scope.updateWeekCBox();
    }
...
    $scope.valueSundayChange = function(index)
    {
        $scope.updateWeekendCBox();
    }

$scope.updateWeekendCBox = function()
{
    if ($scope.saturdayCBox.value==false || $scope.sundayCBox.value==false)
    {
        $scope.weekendCBox.value = false;
    }
    if ($scope.saturdayCBox.value==true && $scope.sundayCBox.value==true)
    {
        $scope.weekendCBox.value = true;
    }
 }
 $scope.updateWeekCBox = function()
 {
      if ($scope.mondayCBox.value==false || $scope.tuesdayCBox.value==false || $scope.wednesdayCBox.value==false || $scope.thursdayCBox.value==false || $scope.fridayCBox.value==false)
      {
          $scope.weekCBox.value = false;
      }
      if ($scope.mondayCBox.value==true && $scope.tuesdayCBox.value==true && $scope.wednesdayCBox.value==true && $scope.thursdayCBox.value==true && $scope.fridayCBox.value==true)
      {
            $scope.weekCBox.value = true;
      }
}
```

If you have any idea, I'd be very glad

Answer (score 0):

Delete the first condition:

```
$scope.updateWeekendCBox = function() {
    ̶i̶f̶ ̶(̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶s̶a̶t̶u̶r̶d̶a̶y̶C̶B̶o̶x̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶=̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶|̶|̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶s̶u̶n̶d̶a̶y̶C̶B̶o̶x̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶=̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶)̶ 

        $scope.weekendCBox.value = false;

    if ($scope.saturdayCBox.value==true && $scope.sundayCBox.value==true)
    {
        $scope.weekendCBox.value = true;
    }
 }
```

And:

```
$scope.updateWeekCBox = function(){
     ̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶(̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶m̶o̶n̶d̶a̶y̶C̶B̶o̶x̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶=̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶|̶|̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶t̶u̶e̶s̶d̶a̶y̶C̶B̶o̶x̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶=̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶|̶|̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶w̶e̶d̶n̶e̶s̶d̶a̶y̶C̶B̶o̶x̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶=̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶|̶|̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶t̶h̶u̶r̶s̶d̶a̶y̶C̶B̶o̶x̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶=̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶|̶|̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶f̶r̶i̶d̶a̶y̶C̶B̶o̶x̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶=̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶)̶

          $scope.weekCBox.value = false;

      if ($scope.mondayCBox.value==true && $scope.tuesdayCBox.value==true && $scope.wednesdayCBox.value==true && $scope.thursdayCBox.value==true && $scope.fridayCBox.value==true)
      {
          $scope.weekCBox.value = true;
      }
}
```

For obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes you're right I've corrected my conditions but it doesn't work, it's like the JS code is updated because the weekendCBox and weekCBox values are ok but the html checkbox is not updated, I tried to use $apply but when I do that I've got an error saying $apply already in progress. I don't understand why it's work in a way and not on the reverse

Answer (score 0):

It's not the correct way to do that but I succeed in doing :

```
document.getElementById('Id').checked = true;
```

So I close the post. Thank you for your help